# Stop Echo server on api call in golang

Tags: go, server, terminal, echo

I am new to Golang and Echo framework. I have started a server using code as shown below and want to stop the server on an API hit which is `/stopServer`. Google making me more confused as I am not able to find this on the API hit. All I am able to see is stopping server on terminal interrupt. Any pointers would be appreciable.

```
func stopServer(c echo.Context) error {
    //Some code which I am not sure about
}

func main() {
    // Echo instance
    e := echo.New()

    e.GET("/stopServer", stopServer)

    // Start server
    e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":1323"))
}
```

I would also like to print the message on `http://localhost:1323/stopServer` saying `"Server stopped successfully"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow the Graceful Shutdown Recipe source code.

[echo Graceful Shutdown Recipe](https://echo.labstack.com/cookbook/graceful-shutdown/)

[more option](https://echo.doc.xuwenliang.com/cookbook/graceful-shutdown/)

and refer following code snippet

```
package main
import (
    "context"
    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
    "net/http"
)
func stopServer(c echo.Context) error {
    err := c.Echo().Shutdown(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        if err != http.ErrServerClosed {
            c.Echo().Logger.Fatal("shutting down the server")
        }
}
    return nil
}
func main() {
    e := echo.New()
    e.GET("/stopServer", stopServer)
    e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":1323"))
}
```

However this will immediately shutdown the echo server and "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" returned to the client.

Comment: make sure to use  go1.8+

Comment: Thanks for the early comment. I checked it's working with the code snippet you shared. Can you also let let me know how to show some message on hitting http://localhost:1323/stopServer that server has stopped? Cause on hitting the URL it just shows "This site can't be reached" page.

Answer (score 0):

the answer about `err := c.Echo().Shutdown(context.Background())` is correct. The only thing that I could add is a `recover()` instead of the application panic. Something like this:

```
func main() {
defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            fmt.Println("host finished")
        }
    }()
    e := echo.New()
    e.GET("/stopServer", stopServer)
    e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":1323"))
}
```